# How to use amqsput command in shell script to push data into a queue?

Tags: shell, ibm-mq, rhel

I am using following command to push some data into a Message Queue.

```
 amqsput QUEUE_NAME QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME
```

[image]

Then after console available I push my required data. (just shown in the screenshot, I will copy my data now).

Since there is a wait involved, Like I first I need to make sure that it connected with the queue through that queue manger then I push my data. Which successfully works.

How can I do it through a shell script?

**Update:**
In shell script I can try following

```
 #!/bin/ksh 
 /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsput QUEUE_NAME QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME < /filepath/data.txt
```

But I can't push string. After < it expects a file.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The `amqsput` is a sample IBM MQ application. Source code, `amqsput0.c`, for this sample application is shipped with product. You can modify this sample per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe text in from an `echo` or `printf` command, like this:

```
printf "%s\n\n" test123 | /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsput SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
```

I've used `printf` here rather than `echo`, because different systems sometimes have different implementations of `echo`, with different ways of handling new line characters (the "amqsputc" command considers two new line characters as the end of the input).

You can even use this if you need to use password authentication on a client channel, like this:

```
export MQSERVER="PASSWORD.SVRCONN/TCP/1.2.3.4(1414)"
export MQSAMP_USER_ID=johndoe
printf "%s\n%s\n\n" passw0rd test123 | /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsputc SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
```